How to use HiltViewModel in compose appoverlay screen
I have implemented the Appoverlay screen in Compose. I can show the screen top-up of other applications or mobile home screens.
Using the Android lifecycle, state registerOwenr(SavedStateRegistryOwner, ViewModelStoreOwner, HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory) can use the view model without hilt dependency injection.
I want to use the hilt dependency injection in the overlay application. Since the Overlay app is not using any Activity like (ComponentActivity/AppCompactActivity). To show the Overlay widget screen open the application and after showing the overlay widget kill the application. So Overly widget still running.
From hilt https://developer.android.com it is mentioned Hilt only supports activities that extend ComponentActivity, such as AppCompatActivity. is there any such a way where we can modify or override the HiltViewModelFactory.
From https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android
reference part

HiltNavBackStackEntry class

This is our code in compose. for overlay, we are using a floating window.
val viewModel: OnBoardingViewModel = hiltViewModel()


FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.harman.caep.space5.companion, PID: 26061                                                                                                  **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected an activity context for creating a HiltViewModelFactory but instead found: android.app.ContextImpl@74633f5  **                                                                                                   at androidx.hilt.navigation.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltNavBackStackEntry.kt:70)

fun NavGraphBuilder.onBoardingGraph(
    navController: NavController,
    onboardingSave: () -> Unit
) {

    navigation(startDestination = Screen.Registration.route, route = OnBoardingNavGraphRoute) {
        composable(route = Screen.Registration.route) {
            val viewModel: OnBoardingViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val uiState = viewModel.registrationScreenUiState.collectAsState()
            RegistrationScreen(
                //uiState.value,
                onRegistrationDataSave = {
                    navController.navigate(Screen.SeatSelection.route)
                }
            )
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Login.route) {
            val viewModel: OnBoardingViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val loginScreenUiState = viewModel.loginScreenUiState.collectAsState()
            LoginScreen(loginScreenUiState.value)
        }
    }
}

